# Converting a Summation to an integral

Tags: calculus, probability, optimization, decision-theory

Please how do I convert this summation 
$$
\frac{r-1}{n} \sum_{i=r}^n \frac{1}{i-1}
$$
to the integral
$$
x \int_x^1 \frac{1}{t} dt = -x \ln x?
$$
by substituting $x = r/n$, $t=1/n$ and $dt =1/n$.  This integral is from the [Secretary Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem).

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mind restructuring and reformatting your question so that it is readable?

Comment: Thanks @Robin and Sammy for helping restructuring the question, I didn't know how to add the maths symbols here.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed $r$, we have

$$
\frac{r-1}{n} \sum_{i=r}^n \frac{1}{i-1} =( r-1 )\sum_{i=r}^n \left(\frac{1}{i-1}\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
When $n$ goes to $+\infty$, we have

$$
(r-1) \sum_{i=r}^n \left(\frac{1}{i-1}\frac{1}{n}\right) \to (r-1)\int_{r-1}^1 \frac{1}{t}dt
$$

Comment: Thanks @Petit: I'm trying to get x= r/n so can I assume rightly that as n tends to infinity, r-1/n is approximately r/n which I can substitute as x. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @AloagbayeItrustGodMomodu in the result, $r$ remains when $n$ goes to infinity. Maybe we shouldn't consider $\frac{r}{n}$ as a whole

Comment: ok thanks a lot.

Comment: @AloagbayeItrustGodMomodu you are welcome